# Diagram showing all tex-related methods/approaches/engines

Tags: tex-general

are you aware of a diagram showing all the connections between tex-related methods/engines. It would use terms such as tex - latex - context - luatex - xetex - xelatex - pdftex - pdflatex - etex and could even be extended to terms like xdvipdfmx and so on?
All this is getting confusing, I think and it would be a good way to summarize. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arno Trautman has a great overview document with graphical representations of these connections:

```
http://github.com/alt/tex-overview
```

It's released on CTAN, yet, but I think it will be soon. I hear that suggestions and contributions for the missing bits'n'pieces (e.g., xdvipdfmx) are gratefully accepted `:)`.